# Block not deleted from DB

Tags: php, block, overriding, concrete5

Situation:
I'm developing a package for **Concrete 5 Version 5.6.3.1**.

The problem:

- When deleting an already published block from the frontend (like any
  user does), the corresponding row in the DB-table isn't deleted.
- When deleting the block without publishing, it works.

Here's my controller

```
class PcShooterChShowSomeThingsBlockController extends Concrete5_Controller_Block_Content {
    protected $btName = "Show Some Things";
    protected $btTable = 'btPcShooterChShowSomeThings';
    protected $btInterfaceWidth = 500;
    protected $btInterfaceHeight = 400;
    protected $btWrapperClass = 'ccm-ui';

    //...
    public $pkgHandle = 'pc_shooter_ch_show_some_things';

    //...



/**
 * --------------- Overrides ----------------------
 */

    public function delete() {
        $db = Loader::db();
        //Log::addEntry('DELETE FROM ' . $this->btTable . ' WHERE bID = ' . $this->bID);
        $db->Execute('DELETE FROM ' . $this->btTable . ' WHERE bID = ' . $this->bID);
        parent::delete();
    }
}
```

The block itself works well, the package too. It isn't My first package at all, also I develop block/packages as recommended by C5.

I start thinking, its a bug, but before I post something on C5, I'm interested to hear from other C5 developers...

In the forum of C5 it says, that overriding the `Concrete5_Controller_Block_Content`'s delete-method helps.

Also I tried to call the `parent::delete();` at the beginnig instead of the end, but no difference.

**UPDATE**
The parents delete method from the `Concrete5_Library_BlockController`:

```
/**
 * Automatically run when a block is deleted. This removes the special data
 * from the block's specific database table. If a block needs to do more 
 * than this this method should be overridden.
 * @return $void
 */
    public function delete() {
        if ($this->bID > 0) {
            if ($this->btTable) {
                $ni = new BlockRecord($this->btTable);
                $ni->bID = $this->bID;
                $ni->Load('bID=' . $this->bID);
                $ni->delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**

Cache settings print screen

[image]

And, maybe it helps, the `db.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema version="0.3">
    <table name="btPcShooterChShowSomeThings">
        <field name="bID" type="I">
            <key />
            <unsigned />
        </field>
        <field name="desc_true" type="I2">
        </field>
        <field name="block_css_style" type="C" size="255">
        </field>
        <field name="block_css_id" type="C" size="255">
        </field>
        <field name="block_css_class" type="C" size="255">
        </field>
        <field name="title_css_class" type="C" size="255">
        </field>
        <field name="desc_css_class" type="C" size="255">
        </field>
    </table>
</schema>
```

If you need any further infos or code, just tell me. I'd be glad to get some tips on this.

**UPDATE 2**

A uninstall/install of the package does not help neither.

**UPDATE 3**

- When deleting an already published block from the frontend (like any
  user does), the corresponding row in the DB-table isn't deleted
  **and no delete() method is firing, neither myne nor the parent's**

Comment: No C5 developer out there? Is this a silent way to tell me to change CMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally, I've got an answer from a developer of the C5-team:

> Not a bug. Blocks still store their data so that they can be
>   reinstated in case a previous version of a page gets approved and
>   rolled back to. Block's will only call BlockController::delete() when
>   they no longer need to keep their data around.

For other C5 developers:

Go to Dashboard > System & Settings > Automated Jobs (under "Optimization") and run the job:

"Remove Old Page Versions"

The child's (or parent's) delete method is firing.
The block is deleted.

Thx to [Andrew Embler](http://www.concrete5.org/profile/-/4/) from the C5-Team!